# Property initializers not defined until declared

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am trying to use property initializers to use arrow functions as methods of a class.
But they are not accessible until the method is declared.
If i change the order in which they are declared it works.

Is it expected behaviour or is it a babel transpilation

```
class SampleClass1 {
  method2 = this.method1();
  method1() {
    return "works";
  }
}

console.log((new SampleClass1()).method2); // Works

class SampleClass2 {
  method2 = this.method1();
  method1 = () => {
    return "works";
  }
}

console.log((new SampleClass2()).method2); // Error
```

Following url is a babel repl instance with the code i want to demonstrate please refer to it.

https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20SampleClass1%20%7B%0A%20%20method2%20%3D%20this.method1()%3B%0A%20%20method1()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22works%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22(new%20SampleClass1()).method2%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log((new%20SampleClass1()).method2)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20SampleClass2%20%7B%0A%20%20method2%20%3D%20this.method1()%3B%0A%20%20method1%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22works%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22(new%20SampleClass2()).method2%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log((new%20SampleClass2()).method2)%3B

Comment: Your second block is missing a }.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for pointing the mistake in the question description, in my codebase i have it right. The problem i am facing is a conceptual one

Comment: I think that's the correct behaviour, 
you can't store a result of a function call before it's definition.

Comment: @Hitmands but if method1 is a class method. it works fine.

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma it is same as in sample: `(function(){var a=test(); function test(){return "ok"}  })()` vs `(function(){var a=test(); var  test=function(){return "ok"}  })()`

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma what is correct behaviour if you crosslink those properties on each other ?

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma  Keep in mind that you're working with transpilation, class methods are attached to the prototype, property initializers are instantiated when the class is called with the new operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. Remember that the syntax from this ESnext proposal draft basically desugars to

```
class SampleClass1 {
  constructor() {
    this.method2 = this.method1();
  }
  method1() {
    return "works";
  }
}

class SampleClass2 {
  constructor() {
    this.method2 = this.method1();
    this.method1 = () => {
      return "works";
    }
  }
}
```

And it's obvious that you can call prototype methods from the constructor, but not methods on instance properties that you haven't yet created.

Comment: ES8 looks weird. Maybe just "class properties proposal"?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try to explain it in a different way and context is going to be Babel transpilation and ES2016.

#### Assignment creates variables.

In `SampleClass2` `method1` is just a variable, which happens to have a function as its value.

```
class SampleClass2 {
  method2 = this.method1(); // variable
  method1 = () => {  // oops, variable because of assignment.
    return "works";
  }
}
```

Think about this as the constructor didn't get to construct an object containing methods, but only got two variables.

Now, since you defined `method1` later, `method2` is undefined. Then you try to call something undefined.

**That's the reason for the error message.**

If you remove `()` like this:

```
class SampleClass2 {
  method2 = this.method1; // no longer an error
  method1 = () => {
    return "works";
  }
}
```

You'd get no error while instantiating `SampleClass2`.

#### Why the first case worked?

```
class SampleClass1 {
  method2 = this.method1();
  method1() {
    return "works";
  }
}
```

This is basically saying that put the function named `method1` into the prototype of `SampleClass1` and while building a new object, assign a variable named `method2` the returned value of the method[sic] `method1`.

#### Don't believe the prototype related stuff.

Check out the following code in Babel.

```
console.log(SampleClass1.prototype.method1) // function body
console.log(SampleClass2.prototype.method1) // nothing
```

Let me know if I missed something or made a mistake. Hope it helps. :)